# React native iOS codepush failed

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, code-push

The image is about my process, can any one help please?

[image]

Comment: Questions where we need to click some link before we even have a chance to understand what you are asking are never good question. Read our [tour] to get basic grasp on how this site works and perhaps [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as well, and then rewrite your question, please. Don't be afraid if it's set "on hold" meanwhile, this is to give you time to edit it; we will open it again once it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your link, it doesn't look like you set your JS bundle location to [CodePush bundleURL] in your AppDelegate.m file, which would prevent the app from retrieving the new JS update after your downloaded an update and restarted the app.

Comment: I set my JS bundle location to [CodePush bundleURL] in my AppDelegate.m file, but my app doesn't change

Comment: Can you take a look at the logs in either Xcode or Chrome to see if any issues are happening as part of the sync?